# Delete nested hidden files with egrep and xargs

Tags: regex, bash, terminal, grep

I'm trying to remove all directories and files that are hidden and recursively remove them. the only hidden directories at current directory level are `.` and `..` but each of several directories has several hidden files (begin with `._`) within them. `ls -aR | egrep '^\.\w+' |` will list out all the files I want easy enough, but adding '| xargs 'rm'` gives me the rm error "No such file or directory".

I take this to mean that each directory I'm trying to remove needs to be appended with it's parent directory and `/`. But maybe I'm wrong.

How can I update this command to delete these files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find . -type f -name .\* -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The `-exec` is white-space safe: `{}` will pass the file path (relative to `.`) as a single argument to `rm`.

Better is this:

```
find . -name .\* -delete
```

(with thanks to @John1024). The first form spawns a process for each file found, whereas the second form does not.

`xargs` by default is not white-space safe:

```
$ touch a\ b
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name a\ \* | xargs rm
rm: cannot remove ‘./a’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘b’: No such file or directory
```

This is because it splits it's input on white-space to extract the file names. We can use another separator character; from `man find`:

> ```
>   -print0
>           True; print the full file name on the standard output,  followed
>           by  a  null  character  (instead  of  the newline character that
>           -print uses).  This allows file names that contain  newlines  or
>           other  types  of white space to be correctly interpreted by pro‐
>           grams that process the find output.  This option corresponds  to
>           the -0 option of xargs.
> ```

So:

```
 find . -type f -name .\* -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: or even `-exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: @fedorqui Yes that's what I'd use too ;-)

Comment: Thanks. that is finding hidden dirs in the current directory, but not hidden files within visible dirs.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I had done it wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what does the backslash before the star do?

Comment: It escapes the star, otherwise the shell will expand it to match files in the current directory.

Comment: @John1024 You're absolutely right! In this case, `-delete` is better, but I thought I'd show `-exec` since it has more applications.

Comment: Wouldn't an escaped star match only a literal asterisk? Forgive me, my regex familiarity doesn't seem very compatible with bash.

Comment: And why is the semicolon escaped? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Ah, that's because `-exec` needs to be told where the command to execute (and it's arguments) end, with a `;` (so you always use `-exec ..... \;`). It is escaped to prevent the shell from using it to separate commands. You're welcome!

Comment: @Kenney I have no idea how you learned all this. Thanks so vey much! :)

Comment: Well done; perhaps you could also show the perhaps more familiar way of quoting literal `.*`: `'.*'`

Comment: The `-0` option can reduce white-space problem of gnu find and xargs: `find -0 criteria | xargs -0 command`.

Comment: @Jokester thanks, that was indeed missing from the answer. However my GNU/Linux `find` doesn't have `-0` option, so I opted for `-print0` instead.