# What would be the fastest way to find and remove files?

Tags: bash, find-util

With:

```
Find="$(find / -name "*.txt" )"
du -hc "$Find" | tail -n1
echo "$Find" | xargs rm -r
```

If the file `foo bar.txt` is found, it won't count it with du or remove the file. What would be the best way to escape the spaces?

Comment: Set `IFS` to newline, so that spaces in the variable expansion won't be used as word delimiters.

Comment: `find -delete` is the fastest; [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488712/delete-nested-hidden-files-with-egrep-and-xargs/33488763#33488763).

Comment: @Cyrus: Thanks for cleaning up the other comment, but if you want to retain the shellcheck.net comment, please _recreate it_ to state that _it no longer directly applies_, and that you're simply recommending shellcheck.net  as a generally helpful resource.

Comment: ...in general, "escaping" spaces or other content inside data (as opposed to code) is the Wrong Thing: If you're escaping them to be safe against parsing, that means you're running your data through a parser, when the best-practice approaches don't do that at all.

Comment: ...it's much the same thing as how trying to escape values that are going into SQL is The Wrong Thing, as opposed to the correct practice of passing them out-of-band (ie. via bind parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If none of your filenames can have *embedded* newlines (which would be very unusual), you can use the following:

<sup>Note: To prevent accidental deletion of files while experimenting with the commands, I've replaced `/` as the input dir. (as used in the question) with `/foo`.</sup>

```
# Read all filenames into a Bash array; embedded spaces in
# filenames are handled correctly.
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra files < <(find /foo -name "*.txt")

# Run the `du` command:
du -hc "${files[@]}" | tail -1

# Delete the files.
rm -r "${files[@]}"
```

---

Note that if you didn't need to collect all filenames ahead of time and don't mind running `find` twice, you can use a single `find` command for each task (except for piping to `tail`), which is also the most robust option (the only caveat is that if you have so many files that they don't fit on a single command line, `du` could be invoked *multiple* times).

```
# The `du` command
find /foo -name "*.txt" -exec du -hc {} + | tail -n1

# Deletion.
# Note that both GNU and BSD `find` support the `-delete` primary,
# which supports deleting both files and directories.
# However, `-delete` is not POSIX-compliant (a POSIX-compliant alternative is to
# use `-exec rm -r {} +`).
find /foo -name "*.txt" -delete
```

Using `+` to terminate the command passed to `-exec` is crucial, as it instructs 
`find` to pass as many matches as will fit on a single command line to the target command; typically, but not necessarily, this results in a *single* invocation; effectively `-exec ... +` is like a built-in `xargs`, except that embedded whitespace in arguments is *not* a concern.

In other words: `-exec ... +` is not only more robust than piping to `xargs`, but - due to not needing a pipeline and another utility - also more efficient.

Comment: I agree that embedded newlines are rare, but what's the point of an approach that's fragile in the face of them? Is the goal compatibility with POSIX find?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: The stand-alone `find` commands avoid the embedded newline issue, in a manner suggested in your helpful comments on the question (although a _single_ invocation of `du` is not guaranteed). Otherwise, it's a tradeoff between between convenience / efficiency and covering _all_ edge cases. Can you think of a fully robust way to collect all filenames without a loop and without involving a temporary file?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `find / -name '*.txt' -exec du -hc {} \;` is more like what you're looking for?

But, doing it as you did, you're missing quotes in your call to `du`, and needlessly using `xargs` when it won't work… You seem enamoured of `echo`, who is not your friend.

Since `\0` isn't allowed in filenames, you can safely collect results from `find` using its `-print0` option:

```
 date > /private/var/mobile/Documents/Local\ Cookies/Clean

 find . -print0 | while IFS='' read -r -d '' file
 do
      du -hc "$file" | tail -n 1
      rm "$file"
 done
```

*Corrected* should work on MacOS and Linux now.

Comment: To get `du -hc` to work as intended (report the _total_ size), you must pass _all_ filenames to it; hence: `-exec du -hc {} +`.

Comment: Your loop solution, aside from being inefficient, has the same problem: invoking `du -hc` on _individual_ files is not what the OP intended. Also, you probably forgot to remove `xargs` before the `rm` command.

Comment: right, cut-n-paste error. And … yeah, I could interpret the intent either way, as far as `du`. The `rm -r` has me puzzled, as well … unless someone has directories named *.txt?

Comment: Re `rm -r`: strange, indeed; as for `du`: from the OP's own solution attempt it's obvious to me that the intent is to _sum up all file sizes_ and report the _total_ size (byte count).